# X numbers that when subtracted will produce the same absolute value

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value

Let's say I have *x* unique numbers and I choose one number *y* out of this set. Is it possible to create these *x* numbers such that the *absolute* difference between *y* and any *other* number in $x$ will always be the same? This should work for every value of *y* in *x*.

This is trivial for $x = 2$ ...

```
Numbers: -1, 1
|(-1) - 1| = 2
|1 - (-1)| = 2
```

But with $x > 2$ this seems more complicated (or impossible?). What are your thoughts?

Is it possible to accomplish this with $x > 2$ so the difference is at least *almost* the same?

Comment: With real numbers, $X\gt 2$ implies that there are duplicated numbers in the set.  With complex numbers, there can be as many numbers in your set as you wish...  Of course, even with the complex numbers there is still a limitation where there are only certain $y$ such that the count of other numbers in the set which are equidistant from $y$ is greater than a certain amount...

Comment: Or, if you choose an open disk in the complex plane as your set $X$ then every $y$ has an infinite number of values around it which are equidistant from it...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Take three numbers $a, b, c.$ Say that $a+b=c$. From that information, we can make a set of fact families:

$$a+b=c$$
$$b+a=c$$
$$c-b=a$$
$$c-a=b$$

These are the traditional equations in a fact family. But we can add one more.

$$b-c=-a$$

This is the most important one for our problem. We know it is true, because we can subtract $c$ and subtract $a$ from both sides of the first equation.

Now we can look at two important equations:

$$c-b=a$$
$$b-c=-a$$

These have a lot of relation to our first problem. We can put absolute value in:

$$|c-b|=a$$
$$|b-c|=a$$

And there you have it. No matter what $b$ and $c$ are, the two equations above will always be true.